# How can I make a program return to the beginning?

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, insert the following information that we are asking you for: ");
        Console.Write("Name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("LastName: ");
        string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Age: ");
        int age =Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Gemder: ");
        string gender = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Nationality: ");
        string nationality = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Job: ");
        string job = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine($"ARE YOU SURE THESE IS YOUR REAL INFORMATION?: {name} {lastName} {age} {nationality} {job} ");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        
        
            if (answer == "Yes")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Now you are a part of the office");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please, insert the correct answer....");
            
            }
        
        


        Console.ReadLine();
```

First of all sorry if you don't get my english, I'm still learning... well, basically what I want is: if the user respond is "no" the program itself get back to the first question in order the user to insert
the right answer, thanks beforehand for your help

Comment: Use whatever documentation you are using to learn the language and look up *loop* or *looping*. Loop statements include `for`, `foreach`, `while` and `do/while`. The latter two are more applicable here. Stay away from `goto`

Comment: Thanks to each and every one of you, now the program works well...

Answer (score 0):

To make a program return to the beginning, use a loop around the entire program body.

Comment: Thanks dude, now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while(true)` and if the user answers yes you can `break;` for example:

```
while(true)//at the beginning of your code
{
    string answer = Console.ReadLine()
        if (answer == "Yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now you are a part of the office");
            break;
        }
        else if (answer == "No")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, insert the correct answer....");
        
        }
  }
```

So in conclusion your code will look like this:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please, insert the following information that we are asking you for: ");
    Console.Write("Name: ");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("LastName: ");
    string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Age: ");
    int age =Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Gemder: ");
    string gender = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Nationality: ");
    string nationality = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Write("Job: ");
    string job = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"ARE YOU SURE THESE IS YOUR REAL INFORMATION?: {name} {lastName} {age} {nationality} {job} ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    
    
        if (answer == "Yes")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now you are a part of the office");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, insert the correct answer....");
        
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make it bold with a loop, maybe a while loop.

Comment: I used a do/while loop and now the problem is fixed, thanks a lot.